# Passing base64Binary type in nusoap

Tags: php, web-services, base64, nusoap

I am using NuSOAP in PHP and using a web service built in Java.

When calling NuSOAP, I pass this argument:

```
$args[]=array('name'=>'content', 'value'=>base64_encode($content), 'type'=>'Base64Binary');
```

However, when examining the SOAPXML, I see the following:

```
<content xsi:type="xsd:string">PD94bWwgdmVywIiBlbmNvZ....cmQ+DQoNCg==</content>
                  Note:^^^^^^
```

In nusoap.php, I see the following:

```
/*
$Id: nusoap.php,v 1.123 2010/04/26 20:15:08 snichol Exp $

NuSOAP - Web Services Toolkit for PHP
...
*/
...
    /**
    * XML Schema types in an array of uri => (array of xml type => php type)
    * is this legacy yet?
    * no, this is used by the nusoap_xmlschema class to verify type => namespace mappings.
    * @var      array
    * @access   public
    */
    var $typemap = array(
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' => array(
        'string'=>'string','boolean'=>'boolean',...,'base64Binary'=>'string', ...),
    'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema' => array(...,'base64Binary'=>'string','base64'=>'string','ur-type'=>'array'),
    'http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema' => array(...,'base64Binary'=>'string','base64'=>'string','ur-type'=>'array'),
    'http://soapinterop.org/xsd' => array('SOAPStruct'=>'struct'),
    'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' => array('base64'=>'string','array'=>'array','Array'=>'array'),
    'http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap' => array('Map')
    );
```

Note that in all instances,

```
'base64Binary'=>'string'
```

Which is probably why I'm facing this error! Why is this conversion of type taking place and is it safe for me to modify this file and do:

```
'base64Binary'=>'base64Binary'
```

Answer (score 0):

The php base64_encode functionality returns a string. So nusoap is reading the type correctly. try referencing the content without encoding it first.

```
$args[]=array('name'=>'content', 'value'=>$content, 'type'=>'Base64Binary');
```

C.

Comment: hi, that was an interesting solution, but it didnt work... I'm still getting the same error!

Comment: (interesting idea is what i meant to say)